# Fight Club 5 to printable Character Sheet

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, character-creation

I'm wondering if there is an app or website that would enable me to convert a fight club 5 character into a printable character sheet?

I've done a quick google search but I wasn't able to find anything

The use case is I'm thinking about running some one-shot and two-shot campaigns which will be open to drop-in/out players. As part of the one shot I'd like to have some pre-rolled character sheets to give to players, but also have the flexibility to level them up between sessions, without having to write them out.

Comment: What is fight club 5?

Comment: It's an app that allows you to store your D&D characters while managing things like their stats during a game.

Comment: This isn't really a "shopping" request. I've already decided to use a specific D&D ecosystem (Fight Club 5 and GameMaster 5) for managing my games. I'm asking if there exists either a feature of that ecosystem I'm missing or a site that provides the feature. If it doesn't exist within the extended ecosystem I'm ok with looking into rolling my own tool to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you ever end up building a tool to do this?  Sounds like a pretty big project.  I'm also looking for the same thing; all I found was this question and a reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/48zz23/fight_club_5_app_printing/

One option if your players are amenable to using the app on their own devices would be to export the characters to Google Drive or DropBox and give the players access to that xml file from there.